# What monitor is thread blocked on?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Wondering if there's a programmatic way to get the object that a thread, if in blocked state, is waiting to get a lock on?

Comment: This is as good as unit testing Java platform's locking implementation, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That's why I specifically wrote about skipping the need for such a test in the context section, and I would still choose to skip the need to avoid digressing from the question. The question is still valid - how do you programmatically get the object that a thread is blocked to get a lock on?

Comment: There's no "regular" way to do that. `Thread.holdsLock(Object)` comes the closest, but it's for checking whether the current thread owns a monitor. I'm certain there's a way to achieve what you want, but then we come back to the question: "why do you want to do something really complex to unit test Java's locking implementation?".

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman. To avoid digressing, I would actually remove the context and leave the question simple. Please treat this more for learning purpose.

Comment: Depending on the JVM vendor , javacore files contain helpful information

Comment: May be first you can tell how you are planning to get the hold of the thread which is in blocked state, problematically.

Comment: If you are trying to debug an application, then there are various tools (Jconsole, etc) and other approaches (kill -3) that will help. One of them is JCarder which is open source and might provide some pointers: https://github.com/jcarder/jcarder

Comment: @hagrawal, I can do `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().enumerate(threads);` to get all the threads which I created from the main thread through a thread pool/completablefuture/whatever. And then look at the threads for which `Thread.getState()` is BLOCKED.

Comment: @Rich, thanks for the pointers, but I'm actually wondering if there's a programmatic way to fetch this information.

Comment: That's why jcarder might be a good place to look. It is open source and has a Java Agent which might show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface [ThreadMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) which was introduced in java 5, comes handy in such scenario. It is very  helpful for managing thread system of jvm. Specially useful in case of deadlocks.

1. You can find [ThreadInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html) for a thread using ThreadMxBean::getThreadInfo, it takes thread id as input.
2. ThreadInfo has a method getLockName() which returns a string representing the monitor object on which a thread is blocked on.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @teeman12, this precisely gives the information I'm looking for. Thank you.